# Why am I getting wrong values in this array?

Tags: ios, arrays

I have a simple action, the equivalent that works fine in a C command line program, but trying to convert this as part of an iOS app is giving me results that I can't work out what the problem is.

The simple action below gets the parameters xCoord, totalCoords and i all in OK as I have tested for them.

In the last line all d values of the array print correctly, but the ones for e and f are just wrong.

Given that arrays start at 0, I made the assignment for i values to [i-1] in the array. I've tried reporting on [g-1] or [h-1] etc., but no, still wrong answers.

In essence, for totalCoords=4, and for i=1 to 4, g should be 4,1,2,3 and h 2,3,4,1.
Must be something obvious, but it beats me.

```
-(void)updateD: (double)xCoord : (int)totalCoords : (int)i
{
    double xCoordArray[totalCoords];
    xCoordArray[i-1] = xCoord;

    g=i-1;

    if(i==1) {
        g+=totalCoords;
    }

    h=i+1;

    if(i==totalCoords) {
        h=1;
    }

    d = xCoordArray[i-1];
    e = xCoordArray[g];
    f = xCoordArray[h];
}
```

Comment: Rename your function first. Never use : without a name before. Also, what is D, what is i?? If I can't understand what a function does from its name then it isn't named properly. The format is `- (void)updateSomeNamedValueWithXCoord:(double)xCoord totalNumberOfCoords:(int)totalCoords atIndex:(int)index;` it just makes everything easier.

Comment: OK, you'll have to provide some context to be able to understand this. At the moment it's hard to understand what it's doing. Could you rename it and provide some examples of what values you are putting in and should be expecting out?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I was trying to make it simple without explaining what each variable does. Most of them don't need an explanation as they are either just counters,for example i, or variables I have put in just for this post, e.g. d, e and f. The bottom line is, given that i goes from 1 to 4 and totalCoords=4, then if d gives correct values, then why are e and f incorrect?

Comment: OK, simple example data is: i is a counter that goes from 1 to 4, totalCoords = 4, and xCoords could be 10,20,30,40. Then d is assigned correctly to 10,20,30,40, e is 0,0,40,0 and f is the same 0,0,40,0. e should be 40,10,20,30 and f should be 20,30,40,10.

Comment: WHAT IS THE FUNCTION SUPPOSED TO DO??

Comment: The function simply puts values into an array (xCoordArray) and different values are pulled out for use later. These are in the variables d e and f. This little routine I posted just demonstrates by using the data supplied that the values are not being assigned correctly for e and f, but are for i-1.  It's easy to do the example I gave manually to see what should come out, but as I said above, the results are very different. I should also say that the values for g and h are being calculated correctly for each value of i.

Comment: You are very good at not explaining what your function is for. We can see that it is pulling values out of an array and storing them. However, we are not asking what is it doing. We are asking "what are you using this for?". If you had to explain it to a child what would you tell them it does?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so...

I'm making some assumptions here. For instance I'm assuming that g and h are irrelevant as you haven't mentioned them.

Also, I'm assuming that what you're actually doing is "rotating" the array.

i.e. you have an array [A, B, C, D, ... , W, X, Y, Z] and you want...

```
d = [A, B, C, D, ... , W, X, Y, Z]
e = [Z, A, B, C, D, ... , W, X, Y]
f = [B, C, D, ... , W, X, Y, Z, A]
```

You appear to be looping through this somewhere so I guess you are trying to get arrays out of it.

I'm making another guess that `xCoordArray` is a `double[]` i.e. a C array not an `NSArray`.

What I'd do is something completely different to this.

First I'd store the values in an NSArray. Anyway... I'd initially do something like this. Then I'd look at refactoring it possibly.

```
// I'll use d, e and f in the same places you have.
NSArray *dArray;
NSArray *eArray;
NSArray *fArray;

NSMutableArray *workingArray;
NSNumber *tempNumber;

// In reality I have no idea what this is, so it's just an example.
// I have used your numbers.
NSArray *xCoordArray = @[@10, @20, @30, @40];

// Your values for d are unchanged so just use the array...
dArray = xCoordArray;

// Your values for e are rotated "forward"...
workingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:xCoordArray];
tempNumber = [workingArray lastObject];
[workingArray removeObject:tempNumber];
// this will "push" everything forward by one index value and place the
// previous "last object" at the front.
[workingArray insertObject:tempNumber atIndex:0];
eArray = workingArray;

// Your values for f are rotated "backwards"...
workingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:xCoordArray];
tempNumber = workingArray[0];
[workingArray removeObject:tempNumber];
[workingArray addObject:tempNumber];
fArray = workingArray;

// results...
// dArray = @[@10, @20, @30, @40];
// eArray = @[@40, @10, @20, @30];
// fArray = @[@20, @30, @40, @10];
```

**EDIT**

You could possibly refactor it by using a function like this...

```
- (NSArray *)arrayByMovingTheFirstOrLastObject:(BOOL)first
                                     fromArray:(NSArray *)inputArray
{
    id tempObject;

    NSMutableArray *workingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:inputArray];

    if (first) {
        tempObject = workingArray[0];
        [workingArray addObject:tempObject];
    } else {
        tempObject = [workingArray lastObject];
        [workingArray insertObject:tempObject atIndex:0];
    }

    return workingArray;
}

// now you can do...
eArray = [self arrayByMovingFirstOrLastObject:NO fromArray:xCoordArray];
fArray = [self arrayByMovingFirstOrLastObject:YES fromArray:xCoordArray];
```

I don't like the name 100% but something like that is much better than what you currently have.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for your huge effort there.  I will look at it in detail tomorrow as it's almost time to go to the land of nod and it's probably a lot better than what I did!  I got it to work by declaring the array values discretely rather than passing them from another action. I think I've confused things here by trying to simplify them!  Still, what you've done looks really interesting and when I wake up tomorrow, I'll go through it and get to you.  Can't thank you enough!

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code gave me some ideas, and the problem was that the array was not retaining values - to cut a long story short.  The only issue I have left, is how do I declare the array variable in the main part of the .m file? Whenever I try to put something like 'double xCoordArray[totalCoords];' xcode complains. I don't want to declare it in the action.  Any help on that?

Comment: To use my code you need to use the NSArray object. Not a primitive array.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate what you are suggesting, but changing what is quite a large program to what you suggest would be a major undertaking, and I have it all working now with the exception of being able to have flexibly defined arrays. It's no real big deal as I'll just have to define them all at a fixed size which is larger than I need. Not very efficient, I know. I thought you might know how to avoid that using 'primitive' arrays.